# Can anyone point me to a sample implementation of an Android Popup Window?

Tags: android, popup

The question says it all. The reference material appears a little sketchy.

Comment: What do you mean "sketchy"... if you're talking about the Android developer's site, then you're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)?

The docs have some pretty straightforward sample code for those.

Comment: lol, I was like "wtf is the OP asking for"... then I saw your answer and it was just like... "oh..."

Comment: @AlexLockwood : The OP might actually be asking about the `PopupWindow` class at which point the docs *are* a little sketchy especially as they say to also see the `AutoCompleteTextView` and `Spinner` classes. I have no idea why those two are listed under *"See Also"*. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: My use of the word 'sketchy' simply referred to the fact that there is no real description of what an Android popup window is, how it relates to an activity, and what features can be implemented using the different methods available.

Comment: @gssi, Sorry, I meant to link to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog in my answer. Assuming you are referring to AlertDialogs when you say "popup," then you can find example code there. If you are more specific as to what is confusing you, we can provide more detailed help as well.

Comment: @Tanis.7x, thank you but I am specifically interested in the android.widget.PopupWindow, a floating container that appears on top of the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this [samples](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

All of these samples has a QuickAction extending a PopupWindows class.

Let me now if this is what you're asking for.